How to prevent an unfiltered query on millions of records?
I have a resource where the default filter uses a limited date range to prevent query failures on the entire database. How can I ensure users either select a narrow date range or, if no date range is specified, provide an alternative filter to avoid querying all records?
I have looked at people overriding the indexQuery but that does not seem to work.
